# Python keyword arguments referencing each other

Tags: python, keyword-argument

When I try the following I get an error

```
def test_func(key1=2.7, key2=key1*3.5):
    print(key1, key2)

NameError: name 'key1' is not defined
```

My solution would be something like

```
def test_func(key1=2.7, key2=None):
    if not key2:
        key2 = key1*3.5

    print(key1, key2)
```

but this looks kind of ugly to me. Does anybody have a better solution?

**edit:**

so my final solution is

```
def test_func(key1=2.7, key2=None):
    if key2 is not None:
        key2 = key1*3.5

    print(key1, key2)
```

thanks for all answers

Comment: maybe you should even change that to an explicit `is key2 is not None`, otherwise users will be unable to pass `0` as the second argument.

Comment: the numbers were just an example, the function i use looks quite different, but you are right. i did not think on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is no better solution.

Function argument definitions can be expressions, but they are evaluated only *once* (which sometimes surprises people, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)).

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be:

```
def t(key1=1, **kwargs):
    key2 = kwargs.get('key2', key1*2.7)
```

getting key2 from kwargs and get data from it with the default key1*2.7

Comment: That has the disadvantage that the user will not get an error if he passes an unexpected parameter, like `key3`. It will just silently ignore it.